# React-Native what is the difference between locationY and pageY

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get X & Y co-ordinates of elements on my screen in the react-native app.

Here is the event that is being fired -

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(evt) => this.handlePress(evt) }>

handlePress(evt)
  {
    console.log(evt.nativeEvent);
  }
```

This is what I got in the console.log output -

```
{"changedTouches": [[Circular]], "identifier": 0, "locationX": 126.46875, "locationY": 356.1696472167969, "pageX": 150.46875, "pageY": 432.7410583496094, "target": 947, "timestamp": 99569733, "touches": []}
```

What is the difference between pageY and locationY value here?

Please let me know if I can explain further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Location (x,y) is relative to the top-left of the component**

> locationX, locationY

**Page (x,y) is relative to the top-left of the device screen**

> pageX, pageY